# How to drag and drop item from Angular 9 application to iframe

Tags: angular, iframe, angular-material, grafana, grafana-api

We have Angular 9 application with embed iframe which is pointed to Grafana dashboard. And we would like to have possibility to drag item from core application and drop it to iframe. Then in background Grafana HTTP API will to be invoked in order to apply action after item dropping. Idea is to create Grafana's panels within its dashboard using drag and drop functionality.

But it seems that iframe does not support needed functionality.

Any ideas how mentioned workflow might be implemented?

Comment: Is the dashboard iframe hosted on the same domain? Otherwise you can't alter it's content using JavaScript.